# Responsive image with multiple background possibles alternative

Tags: css, html, image, responsive-design

So my problem was:

> I wanted mobile / desktop users to possible different images, and retina / non-retina users to see different images.

The goal is to optimize image size depending on the user's screen. So I tried with `<picture>` and `<img srcset=... />` but couldn't make it work so I can up with kind-of-a-hack:

```
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="background-img-responsive" id="image_17691" title="The perfect denim jacket"></div>
  <style type="text/css">
    #image_17691 {
      padding-top: 48.94%;
      background-image: url(/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTQvMDkvMTUvMTcvMDUvMzgvMzQyL1NjcmVlbl9TaG90XzIwMTRfMDlfMTVfYXRfMTEuMzkuMzVfQU0ucG5nIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIxNDEweD4iXSxbInAiLCJlbmNvZGUiLCJqcGciLCItcXVhbGl0eSA0MCAtYmFja2dyb3VuZCB3aGl0ZSAtZmxhdHRlbiJdXQ/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-15%20at%2011.39.35%20AM.jpg);
    }
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dppx) {
      #image_17691 {
        background-image: url(/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTQvMDkvMTUvMTcvMDUvMzgvMzQyL1NjcmVlbl9TaG90XzIwMTRfMDlfMTVfYXRfMTEuMzkuMzVfQU0ucG5nIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIyODIweD4iXSxbInAiLCJlbmNvZGUiLCJqcGciLCItcXVhbGl0eSA0MCAtYmFja2dyb3VuZCB3aGl0ZSAtZmxhdHRlbiJdXQ/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-15%20at%2011.39.35%20AM.jpg);
      }
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      #image_17691 {
        padding-top: 74.64%;
        background-image: url(/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTQvMDkvMTUvMTcvMDUvMzgvMzk5L1NjcmVlbl9TaG90XzIwMTRfMDlfMTVfYXRfMTEuNDAuMTNfQU0ucG5nIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIxMTUyeD4iXSxbInAiLCJlbmNvZGUiLCJqcGciLCItcXVhbGl0eSA0MCAtYmFja2dyb3VuZCB3aGl0ZSAtZmxhdHRlbiJdXQ/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-15%20at%2011.40.13%20AM.jpg);
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3) and (max-width: 767px),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10) and (max-width: 767px),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dppx) and (max-width: 767px) {
      #image_17691 {
        background-image: url(/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTQvMDkvMTUvMTcvMDUvMzgvMzk5L1NjcmVlbl9TaG90XzIwMTRfMDlfMTVfYXRfMTEuNDAuMTNfQU0ucG5nIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCIyMzA0eD4iXSxbInAiLCJlbmNvZGUiLCJqcGciLCItcXVhbGl0eSA0MCAtYmFja2dyb3VuZCB3aGl0ZSAtZmxhdHRlbiJdXQ/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-15%20at%2011.40.13%20AM.jpg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

[image version of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyk2N.png)

Is there a nicer/html5-friendly/future-friendly/with less markup solution?

Comment: Always post the code instead of code screen shot that we can feel your effort while asking a question. Are we here to help effortless question...????

Comment: To change the images for retina and non-retina users you might want to look at [retinajs](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/). This is javascript that swaps an image to retina if the user has a high-dpi screen and a @2x asset is available.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal I think the screenshot is actually more readable. Bastiaan: I don't want retina users to download the image two times

Comment: It sounds like you are serious about serving the correct image based on the device (desktop, tablet, mobile, retina). Because the "picture" element has very limited browser support - http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture - you may want to try this picture polyfill: https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/ Another popular option that uses a different approach is http://adaptive-images.com/ And here is a very useful test page for several different image resizing techniques: http://contentloaded.com/responsive/

Comment: @Talkingrock Basically I tried the `<picture>` element, but it seems like it was based off the size of the image and not the size of the screen

Comment: @Dorian - Here's some useful info. The big concern is loading the correct file size per device/screen size/resolution, and not loading a large file size on handheld, or small size for retina/big screen. The <picture> element with Picturefill is one solution, but there may be easier options. For example, if there are a lot of existing images and you don't want to code each one, adaptive-images might be it (does the heavy-lifting for you). Check this article, and spreadsheet link in the first paragraph for a detailed rundown. http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

Answer (score 0):

Using @media in css is, whether it seems convenient or not, one of the best ways to go about detecting screen sizes without using JavaScript or JQuery. I don't think that this should be considered a hack, because it is efficient, works consistently, and is easy to use.

It is fairly simple to detect retina screens, you would just use:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 

    #image_17691 {
      background-image: url(/media/retina-background.jpg);
    }
}
```

And then for your other non-retina media queries, such as lower resolution smartphones, you would use:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {

    #image_17691 {
        background-image: url(/media/non-retina-background.jpg);
    }
}
```

---

Here are two links that have a list of different CSS media-queries you can use:

[-Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

[-Media Queries for Retina & High Resolution Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)